# XSLT to transform a flat structure to a multi level structure

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Report>
    <BCOT>
        <Detail_Collection>
            <Detail>
                <ElementId>Element1</ElementId>
                <ParentElementId>Element0</ParentElementId>
            </Detail>
            <Detail>
                <ElementId>Element2</ElementId>
                <ParentElementId>Element1</ParentElementId>
            </Detail>
            <Detail>
                <ElementId>Element3</ElementId>
                <ParentElementId>Element2</ParentElementId>
            </Detail>
            <Detail>
                <ElementId>Element4</ElementId>
                <ParentElementId>Element3</ParentElementId>
            </Detail>
            <Detail>
                <ElementId>Element5</ElementId>
                <ParentElementId>Element3</ParentElementId>
            </Detail>
            <Detail>
                <ElementId>Element6</ElementId>
                <ParentElementId>Element1</ParentElementId>
            </Detail>
            <Detail>
                <ElementId>Element7</ElementId>
                <ParentElementId>Element6</ParentElementId>
            </Detail>
            <Detail>
                <ElementId>Element8</ElementId>
                <ParentElementId>Element7</ParentElementId>
            </Detail>
            <Detail>
                <ElementId>Element9</ElementId>
                <ParentElementId>Element8</ParentElementId>
            </Detail>
            <Detail>
                <ElementId>Element10</ElementId>
                <ParentElementId>Element9</ParentElementId>
            </Detail>
            <Detail>
                <ElementId>Element11</ElementId>
                <ParentElementId>Element10</ParentElementId>
            </Detail>
            <Detail>
                <ElementId>Element12</ElementId>
                <ParentElementId>Element11</ParentElementId>
            </Detail>
            <Detail>
                <ElementId>Element13</ElementId>
                <ParentElementId>Element11</ParentElementId>
            </Detail>
            <Detail>
                <ElementId>Element14</ElementId>
                <ParentElementId>Element11</ParentElementId>
            </Detail>
            <Detail>
                <ElementId>Element15</ElementId>
                <ParentElementId>Element9</ParentElementId>
            </Detail>
            <Detail>
                <ElementId>Element16</ElementId>
                <ParentElementId>Element15</ParentElementId>
            </Detail>
            <Detail>
                <ElementId>Element17</ElementId>
                <ParentElementId>Element16</ParentElementId>
            </Detail>
            <Detail>
                <ElementId>Element18</ElementId>
                <ParentElementId>Element16</ParentElementId>
            </Detail>
        </Detail_Collection>
    </BOMConsistOfTmp>
</Report>
```

And I need a stylesheet to get it to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Report>
    <BCOT>
        <Detail_Collection>
            <Detail>
                <ElementId>Element1</ElementId>
                <ParentElementId>Element0</ParentElementId>
                <Detail>
                    <ElementId>Element2</ElementId>
                    <ParentElementId>Element1</ParentElementId>
                    <Detail>
                        <ElementId>Element3</ElementId>
                        <ParentElementId>Element2</ParentElementId>
                        <Detail>
                            <ElementId>Element4</ElementId>
                            <ParentElementId>Element3</ParentElementId>
                        </Detail>
                        <Detail>
                            <ElementId>Element5</ElementId>
                            <ParentElementId>Element3</ParentElementId>
                        </Detail>
                    </Detail>
                </Detail>
                <Detail>
                    <ElementId>Element6</ElementId>
                    <ParentElementId>Element1</ParentElementId>
                    <Detail>
                        <ElementId>Element7</ElementId>
                        <ParentElementId>Element6</ParentElementId>
                        <Detail>
                            <ElementId>Element8</ElementId>
                            <ParentElementId>Element7</ParentElementId>
                            <Detail>
                                <ElementId>Element9</ElementId>
                                <ParentElementId>Element8</ParentElementId>
                                <Detail>
                                    <ElementId>Element10</ElementId>
                                    <ParentElementId>Element9</ParentElementId>
                                    <Detail>
                                        <ElementId>Element11</ElementId>
                                        <ParentElementId>Element10</ParentElementId>
                                        <Detail>
                                            <ElementId>Element12</ElementId>
                                            <ParentElementId>Element11</ParentElementId>
                                        </Detail>
                                        <Detail>
                                            <ElementId>Element13</ElementId>
                                            <ParentElementId>Element11</ParentElementId>
                                        </Detail>
                                        <Detail>
                                            <ElementId>Element14</ElementId>
                                            <ParentElementId>Element11</ParentElementId>
                                        </Detail>
                                    </Detail>
                                </Detail>
                                <Detail>
                                    <ElementId>Element15</ElementId>
                                    <ParentElementId>Element9</ParentElementId>
                                    <Detail>
                                        <ElementId>Element16</ElementId>
                                        <ParentElementId>Element15</ParentElementId>
                                        <Detail>
                                            <ElementId>Element17</ElementId>
                                            <ParentElementId>Element16</ParentElementId>
                                        </Detail>
                                        <Detail>
                                            <ElementId>Element18</ElementId>
                                            <ParentElementId>Element16</ParentElementId>
                                        </Detail>
                                    </Detail>
                                </Detail>
                            </Detail>
                        </Detail>
                    </Detail>
                </Detail>
            </Detail>
        </Detail_Collection>
    </BOMConsistOfTmp>
</Report>
```

I have read that it is better to use templates when I have a recursive task, but I have never fully understood templates as opposed to for-each.

I have tried using a strategy, where I run it a fixed number of times, but I would really like it to work recursively.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Please post what you have tried and we can help fix it.  Think of a template as something that gets "called" in context of your processing.

Comment: Actually I'd say in this case using `for-each` and a `key` would be the right approach. Look for [Muenchian grouping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT/Muenchian_grouping) and [examples](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) for a head start.

Comment: Side note: Keeping the ParentElementId in the resulting doc feels a little awkward and redundant.

Comment: And, using a `for-each` can call a template if it needs to, they are not exclusive

Comment: Both input and output are ill-formed: `<BCOT>` does not match `</BOMConsistOfTmp>`.

Comment: *"I have read that it is better to use templates when I have a recursive task"* Correct.

Answer (score 1):

This is easy to do using a **[key](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#key)** to identify each detail's children (and also the existence of a parent):

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="parent" match="Detail" use="ElementId" />
<xsl:key name="child" match="Detail" use="ParentElementId" />

<xsl:template match="/Report">
    <Report>
        <BCOT>
            <Detail_Collection>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="BCOT/Detail_Collection/Detail[not(key('parent', ParentElementId))]"/>
            </Detail_Collection>
        </BCOT>
    </Report>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Detail">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('child', ElementId)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```